# Need help creating XPATH selectors which depends on the name of the element

Tags: xpath

I wonder if someone can help me. I have an application where user single click on folder icons to open/close it (Similar to how we navigate/explore files in windows explorer tree) - When I am recording my test in selenium IDE here is code that's generated:

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//ul[@id='analysisTree']/li[3]/p</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//ul[@id='analysisTree']/li[4]/p</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Here is a snippet of source code from the application corresponding to the collapsed state of the folders.

```
<li class="folder collapsed" data-nodecode="RentalValues">
<p>Rental Values</p>
<ul>
</li>
<li class="folder collapsed" data-nodecode="Affordability">
<p>Affordability</p>
<ul>
</li>
```

The problem with the current default element xpath locator is that if few months down the line we introduce another folder on the tree it may shift the folder position up or down the tree, which would result in wrong folder being opened. Therefore can someone please help my put together an XPath which would be more robust and would not depend on the exact location of folder in the tree but rather the name of the folder which is unique?

Cheers

Shan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could base the selection on the `data-nodecode` attribute:

```
<tr> 
  <td>click</td> 
  <td>//ul[@id='analysisTree']/li[@data-nodecode='RentalValues']/p</td> 
  <td></td> 
</tr> 
. . .
```

or on the name of the folder:

```
<tr> 
  <td>click</td> 
  <td>//ul[@id='analysisTree']/li[normalize-space(.)='Rental Values']/p</td> 
  <td></td> 
</tr> 
. . .
```

`normalize-space(.)` gets the complete text contained inside the current element (`li` in this case) with extra whitespace stripped off.

Comment: I've tried both of the suggested XPATHs but I am still getting:

[error] Element //ul[@id='analysisTree']/li[@data-nodecode='RentalValues']/p not found

Comment: Can you post your actual input? The snippet in your question seems wrong - it does not contain any `ul` with an `id` attribute, and the nesting of `li` and `ul` is wrong (On the other hand, if that is your actual source the XPath won't work - because the nesting is wrong etc.)

Comment: `<ul id="analysisTree" class="tree">

<li class="file selected " data-nodecode="AreaOverview">
<li class="folder collapsed " data-nodecode="Prices">
<li class="folder collapsed " data-nodecode="RentalValues">
<p>Rental Values</p>
<ul>
<li class="file last " data-nodecode="RentsByBedCount">
<p>Rents by bedcount</p>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="folder collapsed " data-nodecode="Affordability">
</ul>`

Comment: It still does not look ok - the first two `li` and the last one are not closed, and they don't contain any `p`

Comment: I've managed to get this to work - Here is what works for me:

`//li[@data-nodecode='RentalValues']/p`

Thanks for your help MiMO